# Google Charts Vertical Combo vhaxis

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a Google Charts combo chart, I have configured the position of the chart vertically.

I could not add labels to the top and bottom values, nor could I display the values for the top.

How can I display the top and bottom values and also add a label, the label for the top values is 'percentage' and for the bottom values is 'USD'.

This is my actual code:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua New Guinea', 'percentage', 'total'],
      ['2004/05',  165,      938,         522,             998,           45,      614.6],
      ['2005/06',  135,      1120,        599,             1268,          88,      682],
      ['2006/07',  157,      1167,        587,             807,           97,      623],
      ['2007/08',  139,      1110,        615,             968,           15,      609.4],
      ['2008/09',  136,      691,         629,             1026,          66,      569.6]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
    legend: {
        position: 'bottom',
        alignment: 'left'        
      },
      title : 'material production',
      vAxis: {},
      hAxis: {},
      height: 420,
      orientation: 'vertical',
      seriesType: 'bars',
      series: {
       0: {
          pointSize: 5,
          type: 'bars',
        },
        1: {
          pointSize: 5,
          type: 'bars'
        },
         2: {
          pointSize: 5,
          type: 'bars'
        },
        3: {
          pointSize: 5,
          type: 'bars'
        },
        4: {
          pointSize: 5,
          type: 'line'
        },
        5: {
          pointSize: 5,
          type: 'line'
        }
      }
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

I have this jsfiddle which is where I am testing what I need.
https://jsfiddle.net/cruano2/3gpsa9Lo/2/

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to add axis titles?

```
  vAxis: {title: 'Percentage'},
  hAxis: {title: 'USD'},
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua New Guinea', 'percentage', 'total'],
      ['2004/05',  165,      938,         522,             998,           45,      614.6],
      ['2005/06',  135,      1120,        599,             1268,          88,      682],
      ['2006/07',  157,      1167,        587,             807,           97,      623],
      ['2007/08',  139,      1110,        615,             968,           15,      609.4],
      ['2008/09',  136,      691,         629,             1026,          66,      569.6]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
    legend: {
        position: 'bottom',
        alignment: 'left'        
      },
      title : 'material production',
      vAxis: {title: 'Percentage'},
      hAxis: {title: 'USD'},
      height: 420,
      orientation: 'vertical',
      seriesType: 'bars',
      series: {
       0: {
          pointSize: 5,
          type: 'bars',
        },
        1: {
          pointSize: 5,
          type: 'bars'
        },
         2: {
          pointSize: 5,
          type: 'bars'
        },
        3: {
          pointSize: 5,
          type: 'bars'
        },
        4: {
          pointSize: 5,
          type: 'line'
        },
        5: {
          pointSize: 5,
          type: 'line'
        }
      }
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, works good, but  i need to display the other values for percentages in top of this graph, in bottom i have USD, i need to display in top of graph values for percentages.

Comment: not sure I follow, do you simply want to display the word "percentage" on top of the chart? or do you want to display the percentage values of the lines?

Comment: Yes i want to display the percentage values of the lines on top.

Comment: I have this https://jsfiddle.net/cruano2/3gpsa9Lo/12/, but when i use orientation: 'vertical', i lost the right side of charts, i need it rotate complete chart.